# JAVA String vs StringBuffer

Tags: string, object, reference, stringbuffer

Below is the program which confuses me. The output of the below program is

```
 The USA 
main USA
```

If I replace all String to StringBuffer then I am getting 
`"The USA main The USA"`. Please help me to understand this.

```
 public class Confusing {
    public static void sss(String s1){
        s1= "The "+s1;
        System.out.println(s1);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1 = new String("USA");

        sss(s1);
        System.out.println("main "+s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `String` case, in `sss` you modify `s1` only within the scope of `sss`. If you use a `StringBuffer`, you would add something to that `StringBuffer` ... The keyword here is the immutability of `String` in Java ...

Comment: Ok If I make it as "The "+s1; instead of s1 = "The "+s1; then we can say its due to immutablity. Anyways I am passing only reference "s1" in both StringBuffer and String cases. Still I am confused.

Comment: But you add something to the StringBuffer object (with .append, I guess). Because you only pass a reference to that object, this change is also visible in `main`.

Comment: So you mean to say that if I pass String s1 then I am passing by value and if I pass StringBuffer s1 its pass by reference?

Comment: Basically, for StringBuffer, javac throws the semantics of `=` with a reference receiver out the window and modifies the object vs modifying the reference.  (Groan!)

Comment: Java is always pass by value: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm It is just that when you pass an Object, you pass the reference to that object by value ... The trick is within the `+` method of `String`: It does not modify the original String but returns a new one!

Comment: You are correct DaDaDom. Now you have widely opened my eyes. Thanks a zillion.... :)

Answer (score 0):

the right way to do it is like this :

```
public class Confusing {

  public static void sss(StringBuffer s1){
      StringBuffer the= new StringBuffer("the ");

      System.out.println(the.append(s1));
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
      StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer("USA ");

      sss(s1);
      StringBuffer main = new StringBuffer("main ");
      System.out.println(main.append(s1));
 }
}
```

the output is :

```
the USA 
main USA
```